# How can I mine redstone ore?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found redstone ore in Survival Mode (Minecraft Pocket Edition) and tried to use all five tools to collect it. It took about a minute or two to break, but I couldn't collect anything from it once broken.

How do I mine redstone ore?

Comment: The answers to this question are invalid after the release of 0.8 (Dec 2013), in which redstone ore can be mined with an iron tool or better.

Answer (score 11):

<s>[According to the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Ore), it's currently impossible to mine as of version 0.7.1. It can only be destroyed.</s>

Since 0.8.0 build 2, you can now obtain redstone by mining redstone ore with an iron or diamond pickaxe like a normal ore.

Comment: @Flaunting Please refrain from making edits to answers that completely change the answer. Even if you are changing an incorrect answer to a correct one, that is not something that should have been approved. Instead, you should add a new answer with the correct information and a comment/downvote on the outdated answer.

Comment: it wasn't incorrect and i would only be voting to close it otherwise @StrixVaria

Comment: @Flaunting I'm not sure what you mean, but what happened is you approved an edit that completely changed the content of the answer. I am letting you know for future reference, when you are reviewing the queue, that you should be *rejecting* those edits, not approving them or editing them to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mine redstone. I guess it would probably be just decoration and useless to mine. Try waiting for an update where redstone is actually useful. There is no possible way to mine the redstone and you would be wasting your picks. You should wait until the next update.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently impossible to mine redstone ore in Minecraft PE. Just wait until a new update comes out!

Answer (score 0):

You can now mine redstone in the new Minecraft PE update, but the only things you can use redstone to make is clocks, powered rails, and compasses.

Answer (score 0):

For each past version you couldn't have mined redstone without it being destroyed, no matter what material pick axe you used. However, in update 0.8.1. you are able you mine redstone and craft it into clocks, compasses and powered rails. In the new update you still cannot make a redstone block from redstone, so to make that i guess we just have to wait. :(